# Convert embedded blocks into embedded arrays with Ruby

Tags: ruby, dsl

Considering the following [code](http://www.steve.stewdle.com/blog/?p=19):

```
class Node
  def initialize(name=nil)
    @name = name
    @children = []
  end

  def node(name, &block)
    child = Node.new(name)
    @children.push(child)
    child.instance_exec(&block) if block
  end
end

def tree(name, &block)
  @tree = Node.new(name)
  @tree.instance_exec(&block)
  @tree
end

t = tree("Simpsons family tree") do
  node("gramps") do
    node("homer+marge") do
      node("bart")
      node("lisa")
      node("maggie")
    end
  end
end

puts "tree = " + t.inspect
```

Which is returning:

```
tree = #<Node:0x007fca1a103268 @name="Simpsons family tree", @children=[#<Node:0x007fca1a103128 @name="gramps", @children=[#<Node:0x007fca1a102fe8 @name="homer+marge", @children=[#<Node:0x007fca1a102ef8 @name="bart", @children=[]>, #<Node:0x007fca1a102e80 @name="lisa", @children=[]>, #<Node:0x007fca1a102e08 @name="maggie", @children=[]>]>]>]>
```

I would like to know if it was possible to make an update in order to return on-the-fly an embedded array of arrays, without using the `@children` shared array.  I would expect this result:

```
[
  "Simpsons family tree",
  [
    "gramps",
    [
      "homer+marge",
      [
        "bart",
        "lisa",
        "maggie"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Is it possible? Thanks for any suggestions.

**Edit:**
Actually, I would like to do so with basically the same code, but without any `@children` instance. So I want to remove `@children`.

**Edit 2:**

Here is my best result, after some tests:

```
class Node
  def initialize(name=nil)
    @name = name
  end

  def node(name, &block)
    child = Node.new(name)
    @sub = child.instance_exec(&block) if block

    [
      name,
      @sub
    ].compact
  end
end

def tree(name, &block)
  @tree = Node.new(name)

  [
    name,
    @tree.instance_exec(&block)
  ]
end

t = tree("Simpsons family tree") do
  node("gramps") do
    node("homer+marge") do
      node("bart")
      node("lisa")
      node("maggie")
    end
  end
end

puts t.inspect
# => [
#      "Simpsons family tree",
#      [
#        "gramps",
#        [
#          "homer+marge",
#          [
#            "maggie"
#          ]
#        ]
#      ]
#    ]
```

But there's still a trouble with the flatten nodes. Because only the last one is returned by Ruby.

Comment: No, it's not possible if you don't know the array in `@children`.

Comment: Yes you right @Luiggi. Actually I would like to remove this array of arrays. My question wasn't clear enough, I updated it.

Comment: You need to store a node's children somewhere. Why not use `@children`? That is a perfectly appropriate use of an instance variable.

Comment: Because semantically speaking this embedded array is a value, not an object. It should be immutable, defined by itself. So if we can create such array through its initialization process, which is atomic, it would be perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

The formatting of mine isn't exactly what you want, but that's not really the important part.

If you allow your nodes to be initialized with a collection of children, you can have your `node` method return a new node each time it is called.

```
class Node
  def self.new(*args, &block)
    instance = super
    if block
      instance.instance_eval(&block)
    else
      instance
    end
  end

  def initialize(name, children=[])
    @name = name
    @children = children
  end

  attr_reader :children, :name

  def node(name, &block)
    new_node = Node.new(name)
    new_node = new_node.instance_eval(&block) if block
    Node.new(self.name, next_children + [new_node])
  end

  def next_children
    children.map{|child| Node.new(child.name, child.next_children) }
  end

  def inspect
    return %{"#{name}"} if children.empty?
    %{"#{name}", #{children}}
  end
end

t = Node.new("Simpsons family tree") do
  node("gramps") do
    node("homer+marge") do
      node("bart").
      node("lisa").
      node("maggie")
    end
  end
end

puts t.inspect
#=> "Simpsons family tree", ["gramps", ["homer+marge", ["bart", "lisa", "maggie"]]]
```

By changing the behavior of initialization and of the `node` method you can accumulate the nodes as they are created.

I also took the liberty to remove your `tree` method since it was just a wrapper for initializing the nodes, but that might be a place to bring back formatting.

I came across this post looking for examples of good use of `instance_exec` for [my Ruby DSL Handbook](http://clean-ruby.com/dsl) but you can either use `instance_exec` or `instance_eval` for the block since you're not passing any arguments to it.

EDIT: I updated the approach to return new values each time. The change required that nodes without blocks be chained together because each `node` call return a new object. The return value for the block is a new node.

In order to get the formatting you want, you'd need to do `[t].inspect`